# Is point of sale hardware usually connected to the internet? Could they support http requests?

Tags: networking

I have practically no experience or have never worked in a retail environment. I would like to know if POS are usually  connected to the internet to be able to make http requests to a server, or are they usually isolated, perhaps only connected to a central backroom computer who is connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

They are usually stand alone.

I've worked many years in the past (about 5 years ago) with POS and in that moment most POS were connected almost exclusively via phone line to a phone central.

Now they have more ways to communicate with the bank but they are mostly working as an independent terminal against the bank servers (exists however POS that act as peripherals to read card or just put your pin).